# Transformation matrix for rotation about arbitrary axis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, rotations

Specifically, I don't know what approach to take in answering Griffiths' question 1.9 in his introduction to electrodynamics:

> Find the transformation matrix R that describes a rotation by 120
>   degrees about an axis from the origin through the point $(1,1,1)$. The
>   rotation is clockwise as you look down the axis towards the origin.

From [Glen Murray's page](https://sites.google.com/site/glennmurray/Home/rotation-matrices-and-formulas/rotation-about-an-arbitrary-axis-in-3-dimensions) on rotations, the supposed approach to take is successively rotate space so that the rotation axis sits along the z axis $T$, :

$$T = 
\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0 \\ 0& \cos{\alpha} & -\sin{\alpha} \\ 0&\sin{\alpha} & \cos{\alpha} 
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} \cos{\beta} & 0 & \sin{\beta} \\ 0 &1&0 \\ -\sin{\beta} &0 & \cos{\beta} \end{pmatrix}
$$

perform the rotation $\theta$,:

\begin{pmatrix} \cos{\theta} & -\sin{\theta} &0 \\ \sin{\theta} & \cos{\theta}&0 \\ 0&0&1 
\end{pmatrix}

and rotate space back to its original orientation $T^{-1}$.

$T$ first rotates space such that the rotation axis sits in the xz plane. Secondly, it rotates space such that the rotation axis lies along the z axis.

This approach seems overly tedious, as this is an introductory question in an introductory chapter. Am I missing something here?

Where I to proceed in this approach, for the arbitrary axis from the origin through the point $(a,b,c)$, then I would need to derive the angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as follows.

[image: alpha]

$\alpha = \arctan{\frac{b}{a}}$

[image: beta]

$\beta = \arctan{\frac{a\cos{\alpha} +b\sin{\alpha}}{c}}$

Answer (score 1):

You could also just form an orthogonal (change of basis) matrix, $R$, with $\frac1{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}(a,b,c)$ as the last row, to take the $z$-axis to $(a,b,c)$.
Then if $S$ is the rotation about the $z$-axis, our $T$ would be $T=R^tSR$.

See [this example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2835372/403337).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Looking down the axis toward the origin, you see the three axis forming angles of $120°$. This rotation is just a circular permutation of the axis.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I see that you mean the x,y and z axes forming the angles, only how to derive this algebraically?

Comment: @MusséRedi: form an orthogonal frame with $z'$ in the direction $(1,1,1)$ and find the matrix of the change of basis. Then project the axis on the plane $x'y'$.

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: How do you see the three axes forming angles of $120^\circ$, looking down the axis toward the origin?