# Rotational Matrix and the Method in proof

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, rotations

I have a question in computing the transformation in 3D space about a rotation axis passing through the origin matrix. I have no idea what this is about and I am looking for some tips and answers.

Given that the axis of rotation is a vector from (0,0,0) to (1,1,1)
, write a rotation transformation matrix that is rotated inversely by 30 degrees around the axis,and calculate the new coordinates of the space point (1,1,2) after rotating around that axis.

Thank you very much.

Comment: With a change of basis and the wikipedia page you should be able to do it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix. If it seems to hard try to look into how and why matrix represents linear application after we fix a base for the space.

Comment: @MatíasMatteini Thank you for your reply. Wrong me not, the first step should be the dot product of (1,1,1,1) and (cos30, 0, -sin30, 0; 0,1,0,0; sin30,0,cos30,0;0,1,0,1)?

Comment: @ChristiePPP . 3D as in the question or 4D as in this comment ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transformation matrix for rotation about arbitrary axis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3090644/transformation-matrix-for-rotation-about-arbitrary-axis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the axis of rotation is along the unit vector $\mathbf{a}$, and the angle of rotation is $\theta$, then the rotation matrix is given by the Rodrigues' rotation matrix formula, which is

$\mathbf{R} = \mathbf{aa}^T + (\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{aa}^T ) \cos(\theta) + \mathbf{S_a} \sin(\theta) $

where

$\mathbf{S_a} = \large \begin{bmatrix} 0 && - a_z && a_y \\a_z && 0 && -a_x \\ -a_y && a_x && 0 \end{bmatrix} $

In this example, the unit vector along the axis is

$ \mathbf{a} = \dfrac{ [1,1,1]^T}{\sqrt{3} } $

Therefore,

$\mathbf{aa}^T = \dfrac{1}{3} \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 1 && 1 \\ 1 && 1 && 1 \\ 1 && 1 && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

and

$( \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{aa}^T ) = \dfrac{1}{3} \begin{bmatrix} 2 && - 1 && -1 \\ -1  && 2 && -1 \\ -1 && -1 && 2 \end{bmatrix} $

and

$ \mathbf{S_a} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \begin{bmatrix} 0 && -1 && 1 \\ 1 && 0 && -1 \\ -1 && 1 && 0 \end{bmatrix} $

Putting all the pieces together, the rotation matrix is given by

$\mathbf{R} = \dfrac{1}{3} \begin{bmatrix} 1 + 2 \cos \theta && 1 - \cos \theta - \sqrt{3} \sin \theta && 1 - \cos \theta +\sqrt{3} \sin \theta \\
1 - \cos \theta +\sqrt{3} \sin \theta && 1 + 2 \cos \theta && 1 - \cos \theta - \sqrt{3}\sin \theta \\ 1 - \cos \theta -\sqrt{3} \sin \theta && 1 - \cos \theta + \sqrt{3} \sin \theta && 1 + 2 \cos \theta \end{bmatrix}$

The image of the vector $\mathbf{P} = [1,1,2]^T $ under an "inverse" rotation of $30^\circ$ corresponds to the rotation angle being $\theta = -30^\circ$.  The image $\mathbf{P'}$  is given by

$ \mathbf{P'} = \mathbf{RP } $

All you have to do is substitute the value of $\theta$ in the rotation matrix expression and evaluate the multiplication of the matrix $\mathbf{R}$ and the vector $\mathbf{P}$.

Comment: May I know the reason why is a contain the square root of 3 ?

Comment: Because $a$ vector has to be a unit vector.